# uiwebview javascript no return the variable but return the alert

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have this function in javascript:

```
function getResponse(){
    setInterval(function(){
        value = player.getCurrentTime();
        getValue(value);
    },100);
}
function getValue(value){
    var lines  = value;
    //alert("Value is: " + lines);
    return lines;
}
```

And when I want get the lines variable, I don't get any response;

```
NSString *response = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getResponse()"];
NSString *resonse2 = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getValue();"];

NSLog(@"oh %@ %@",response,resonse2);
```

but If I discomment the alert, the alert return a correct response. I don't know what I need to do.

Thanks!

Comment: You returning the lines, but where is it assigned? You are calling the getValue() function without any assignment to a variable or return statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getResponse(){
    setInterval(function(){
        value = player.getCurrentTime();
        getValue(value);
    },100);
}
```

So this function is calling an anonymous function asynchronously after 100 ms.
After 100ms has passed, it sets the `value` to be the current time, and calls `getValue()`
I don't know what or where `value` came from, but I'll make an assumption that it is in scope (maybe global)

```
function getValue(value){
    var lines  = value;
    //alert("Value is: " + lines);
    return lines;
}
```

This function basically just returns the value that it was given. I don't really know the scoping rules of JS, but when you call it from iOS, you are not passing in anything, so maybe its getting the value of the previous (gloabl?) `value` variable.

So what are we doing in iOS?

`NSString *response = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getResponse()"];
NSString *resonse2 = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getValue();"];`

First, we call `getResponse()`, which sets off an async call to `getValue()` *after 100ms*.

Then, we *immediately* call `getValue()` on our own, with no parameters, and get returned to response.

However it works when the alert is shown. My JS knowledge is a little lacking, but I'm guessing it's because showing the alert takes up that time that took while its waiting for those 100ms. Then, by the time the alert is done, the (global?) variable `value` has been filled in by `getResponse()`, which means that it returns the value.

How do we fix this? 
Is there any problem with doing all this synchronously? Do we have to have 2 functions?
My original thought is, why can't we just run this:

```
function getCurrentTime() {
    return player.getCurrentTime();
}
```

?